# Trigger a webhook when a cell is edited by a google sheets function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to call a webhook when a cell is edited in certain range which is f2 to f100

Now I was able to do that if I edit the cell manully but if I let the function to do edit the cell it won't call the webhook

the f field value is `=IF(E2=0,"on","off")`

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to achieve and how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: Based on what little was provided in your inquiry , also note that onEdit is only triggered by manual edits.  See Google documentation here. [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)